# How to restart a for loop in kotlin

Tags: for-loop, kotlin, iteration, restart

I have this nested loop situation in Kotlin, imagine there are two strings "abcdef" and "bfihja". I'm comparing these two character by character using for loop. If there's a match, that character is to be removed from each string and the iteration for "S2" should start from beginning.

```
var S1 = "abcdef"
var S2 = "bfihja"

   for(i in S1.indices) {
      for(j in S2.indices){
          
         if(S1[i]==S2[j]) {
             "character removed from each"
         }
```

What I'm having issues in is, when the character matches, the comparison for "S2" string should start from the beginning again. I can't find  way restart it.

Comment: For this task, I think the code is likely to be both clearer and more efficient if you sort the strings first.  You then need only a single scan through both strings together.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a labeled outer while loop. By using `continue` on the outer loop, you restart your iteration. You can put `break` after the outer iteration so we can exit the while loop when complete.

```
outer@while (true) {
    for (i in S1.indices) {
        for (j in S2.indices) {
            if (S1[i] == S2[j]) {
                S1 = StringBuilder(S1).deleteCharAt(i).toString()
                S2 = StringBuilder(S2).deleteCharAt(j).toString()
                continue@outer
            }
        }
    }
    break
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. If i have understood correctly, what this is doing is, when there's a match the strings are updated and with "continue@outer" the whole loop is starting again with the new strings and when the outer for loop ends it breaks right..?? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regular for-loop that ranges from 0 to `length-of-S2` in the inner for-loop, and just reset the iterator variable to 0 when you want to "reset" the for-loop.

Comment: How to reset the iterator? The val "j" cannot be altered